# How to do `for line.split() in line:` as list comprehension

Tags: python, split, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use python comprehension.

I have a list which is in the format:

```
name_a:surname_a
name_b:surname_b
name_c:surname_c
```

My code initially to split each pair in a line into its own variable was:

```
for lined in self.account:
    a, b = line.split(':')
```

I tried to use this comprehension, but it didn't seem to work:

```
(a,b) = [line.split(':') for line in self.account]
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: You're missing the colon `:` argument to `line.split` in your list comprehension. It should be `(a, b) = [line.split(":") for line in self.account]`

Comment: accident, the colon isn't the problem

Comment: @stilManiac i want to check through list to make sure all lines are split-able

Comment: @coderoftheday Do you actually need the split parts, or are you just testing whether a `:` character exists in every line?

Comment: i want to split it, just to make sure its split-able, but its been answered now

Comment: As long as there's a colon in the line it'll split just fine. You could just do: `all(':' in line for line in self.account)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @MattDMo the colons are missing in your list comprehension. If you add them, a additional problem will appear. If you print the list returned from the list comprehension, it will probably look like this:

```
[['name_a', 'surname_a\n'], ['name_b', 'surname_b\n'], ['name_c', 'surname_c\n']]
```

The problem is, that you can't assign it to two variables, because the list contains the same number of elements as lines in the file.

To get the desired result, you have to transpose the two dimensional list, for example by using zip and unpacking ('*'):

```
>>> with open('test_file.txt') as f:
...   (a, b) = zip(*[line.split(':') for line in f])
...
>>> a
('name_a', 'name_b', 'name_c')
>>> b
('surname_a\n', 'surname_b\n', 'surname_c\n')
```

Comment: `zip(*<listoflist>)`?

Comment: No, the listcomp is **not** correct, see my comment above.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks, I have overseen this issue, but added it in the answer.